# Box with header using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a box with a header. We are using bootstrap for the css [http://getbootstrap.com/]. The box should look like as below. It is part of the responsive design and having the class of span9. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is how I was trying to achieve the same :

CSS and HTML

```css
.container:before, .container:after { display:table; content:""; }

.container:after { clear:both; }

.container { width:500px; margin:0 auto; border:1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow:0px 2px 7px #292929;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929; border-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px; background-color:#ffffff; }

.mainbody { height:250px; width:500px; border: solid #eee;
  border-width:1px 0; }

.header, .footer { height: 40px; width:50px; border : 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px; }

.footer { background-color: whiteSmoke;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px; border-bottom-right-radius:5px; border-bottom-left-radius:5px; }
```

```html
<div class="header container">
  Header
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="mainbody">
    main body
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

[image]

Comment: This community will help you overcome difficutlies, not do the actual work for you.

Comment: what version of bootstrap you are using

Comment: @HTTP - I am using version Bootstrap v3.1.1. I am also trying to find a solution of the same

Comment: I dont know if bootstrap 3 implements the old `spans` e.g. `span9`. I think its now `cols` e.g. `col-sm-2`

Comment: @Anirban What have you tried so far?

Comment: When I was learning CSS, what helped me the most was browse around other websites and see what elements i wanted, then I look at inspect elements and see the CSS. After a period of time, I definitely got better!

Answer (score 3):

I decided to spend the time to do this FOR you, but next time atleast try before you ask AND provide us with what you have tried so we dont make the same mistake that you made.

You need Jquery, and Bootstrap (CSS, and JS).

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is a working demo. http://jsfiddle.net/d45SQ/

Comment: No problem @Anirban Let me know if you need any other bootstrap help. Please mark this as the correct answer if it solved your question. Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately Natham - this is not the solution I was looking for. Please refer to the html and css i entered . I was expecting on thje same lines

Comment: Ok, well I dont understand what you are trying to say. Where is the screenshot from?

Comment: @Anirban Did your problem get solved? If not, where is the screenshot from?